# Why is my event not firing?

Tags: vb.net, transition

I am doing some transition coding, using the .net transitions library found @ http://code.google.com/p/dot-net-transitions/.  I am trying to add an event to fire on transitions completed.  In my sub, I have the following statements:

```
Private Sub btnLogin_Click_1(ByVal sender As System.Object, ByVal e As System.EventArgs) Handles btnLogin.Click

If md5Password = rtnPassHash Then

                AddHandler Me.TransitionCompletedEvent, AddressOf theHandlerFunction

                Dim tr_empID = New Transition(New TransitionType_Linear(500))
                tr_empid.add(txtEmployeeID, "BackColor", Color.LightGreen)

                Dim tr_passw = New Transition(New TransitionType_Linear(500))
                tr_passw.add(txtPassword, "BackColor", Color.LightGreen)

                tr_empID.run()
                tr_passw.run()
                AddHandler Me.TransitionCompletedEvent, AddressOf theHandlerFunction

                Dim tr_empID = New Transition(New TransitionType_Linear(500))
                tr_empid.add(txtEmployeeID, "BackColor", Color.LightGreen)

                Dim tr_passw = New Transition(New TransitionType_Linear(500))
                tr_passw.add(txtPassword, "BackColor", Color.LightGreen)

                tr_empID.run()
                tr_passw.run()

end if

end sub
```

Outside of that sub I have:

```
Public Event TransitionCompletedEvent As EventHandler(Of Transition.Args)

Private Sub theHandlerFunction(ByVal sender As Object, ByVal args As Transition.Args) Handles Me.TransitionCompletedEvent
    MsgBox("Event Fired")

End Sub
```

However, the event is not firing after the transition has finished.  Why would this be?

Comment: What code is the `AddHandler` line in? Is it in an event handler or something else? Can you post the entire method for the first code listing?

Comment: I added a bit above, it is in a sub using button click.  The handler is added after my condition for md5 match, and should theoretically fire after the transition completes.

Comment: The `Addhandler` wires up the event it does not fire the event.

Comment: Do you call `RaiseEvent` in the Transition class? If you don't it will never fire either.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Basic design:

```
Public Class Transition
  Public Event TransitionCompleted(args As Transition.Args)
  Public Sub SomeSub()
    RaiseEvent TransitionCompleted(New Transition.Args With {set some properties})
  End Sub
  ...
End Class

Public Class Form1
 Private transition1 As New Transition
 Private Sub Login_Click(...) ...
  ...
  Addhandler transition1.TransitionCompleted, AddressOf TransitionCompleted
 End Sub

 Private Sub TransitionCompleted(args As Transition.Args) ' no handles clause
   MessageBox.Show("event fired")
 End Sub
End Class
```